# How do I attach socket.io to multiple HTTPServer instances?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

My Express app listens on both HTTP and HTTPS:

```
var app = express()
  , srv = http.createServer(app)
  , ssl = https.createServer({ ... }, app);
```

I can make socket.io listen to one of the servers, but not both:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(srv); // now what about `ssl`?
```

How can I make a single socket.io instance listen to both the HTTP and HTTPS servers?  I want to make one `io.emit(...)` call that will send messages to clients connected on both HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: Just a quick guess, can you do `io.addServer(ssl)`? -- Exact same question on Google group, might help: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/socket_io/eQkQLTexeBk

Comment: @tymeJV: Nope.  There is a `io.addListener`, but that's just an alias of `io.on`.  Proxying (that thread's suggestion) isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one thing you can try based on reading the source (untested):

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/64f6b244b6bd79880ba2e0ba00778a2309b39d0b/lib/index.js#L127

```
var engine = require('engine.io');
var httpsEIO =  engine.attach(server.https, {path: '/socket.io'});
server.ws.bind(eio);
```

or in 0.9-land manually duplicate these bindings:

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/64d8f572aa9291889dd766e7b5832fc6f23b32a3/lib/manager.js#L103

Comment: I believe that code is part of the unreleased socket.io 1.0 rewrite.  I'm still on 0.9.